# Node.js - Mongoose: Search for multiple items in array in documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I (using Node.js and MongoDB through Mongoose) search for an many items in an array in document.

For example, if I have documents like:

```
{
    _id: 123, field1: 'abc', field2: ['def', 'ghi', 'jkl'],
    _id: 456, filed1: 'abc', filed2: ['jkl', 'ghi', 'def']
}
```

And the schema is called schema1, how can I perform a search with a query like

```
{field1: 'abc', field2: ['def', 'jkl']}
```

and get both documents (all documents whose field1 = 'abc' and field2 contains both 2 items in the array in query)?

I tried using `schema1.find()` but it only matches the arrays as a whole not their items. So none of these 2 documents would return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the $all operator with the following query:

```
{
    field1: 'abc', 
    field2: {
        $all: ['def', 'jkl']
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I know why trying $all didn't work for me before =D . Many thanks @Steve

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this same issue my solution was to do something this:

`{field1: 'abc', field2: 'def', field2:'jkl'}`

This should return all documents that have at least both 'def' and 'jkl' inside `field2` and 'abc' in `field1`.
It does look a bit awkward and there may be a better way to write this query, but it does work and is totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch results use

You can use $and for join both condition and to search element in array use $in

db.collectionName.find({ $and : [{ "field1" : "abc"}, { "field2" : { $in : [ "def","jkl"]}}]}).pretty()